# Table com Input Radio - preciso ler os valores de cada linha

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, tenho uma tabela que possui uma coluna com um input radio, preciso ler os valores de cada linha de um input radio sem interferir na ordem das linhas. Exemplo, tenho 3 linhas e selecionei apenas o radio da última linha, preciso que me retorne a função o valor da o radio button na terceira vez que eu leio ele.
Tentei usar o document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked')[indice].value contudo o problema é que ele ordena pelos radio buttons selecionados. Então no cenário que eu expliquei ele retornou primeiro o radio button selecionado e depois trouxe undefined

```js
        var table = document.getElementById("tblpergunta");

        for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
        {
          var CheckListRespostaModel = {
                "PerguntaId": "", "CheckListPendenteId": "", "Observacao": "", "Controle":                 "", "Id" :"",
                "Nome": "", "BytesToString": "", "Extensao": ""
            };
            rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
            CheckListRespostaModel.PerguntaId =  cells[2].innerText;
            alert(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked')[i - 1]);

        }
```

nas outras duas lidas.

Answer (score 0):

Achei a resposta.

```js
 if ($('input[name='+ cells[2].innerText + ']:checked') != null) {
        
       ($('input[name='+ cells[2].innerText + ']:checked').val());
}
```